# Solve mod equation, how?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Ok so how would I solve for $j$:  $(e*j)\bmod z=1$ When $e$ and $z$ are known integers. I am at a loss with this without using trial and improvement. Is there a formula I could use?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the edit.

Comment: What is modular about your question? What is the difference between the $*$ operator and juxtaposition; is the latter something else than multiplication?

Comment: I had to add a tag, since the question involves 'mod', I just assumed it related to said tag, it seems I was incorrect. Sorry, I am no mathematician.

Comment: My bad; there was `%` in the original question, but it was not there when I looked. There is the mathematical equivalent $\bmod$ now.

Comment: Modular inverses are usually computed using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Ok, so this would have to be computed via trial and improvement, there is no one equation?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a modular inverse $j$ of $e$ modulo $z$. It only exists if $\gcd(e,z)=1$, in which case it is a unique class modulo $z$. You can find that class using Bézout coefficients: there exist $s,t\in\Bbb Z$ such that $se+tz=\gcd(e,z)$, and if the latter is $1$ then $j=s$ is a solution of the problem.

Comment: I'm confused, so the value of gcd(e,z) is known, where does t come in?

Comment: Sorry, I said "is" in place of "if" (corrected now). Since $e,z$ are known, you can compute their $\gcd$. Unless the result is$~1$, there will be no solution at all. If it is$~1$, you can find a solution using the Bézout coefficients (which you can find while computing $\gcd(e,z)$).

Comment: So in this instance, how would you use the Bézout coefficients to solve the equation?

Comment: As I said, if $s,t$ are Bézout coefficients, then $j=s$ **is** a solution.